# where to change the Build Action for AndroidManifest.xml to "none?"

Tags: android, xamarin

Warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported (XA0101)

This the error message i am getting. How to resolve this problem

where to change the Build Action for AndroidManifest.xml to "none?"

Answer (score 5):

Right click on `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Select `Properties`.

In `Properties Window` ---> set `Build Action` as `None`

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the GUI for the IDE you are using by opening up the .csproj file in a text editor like Sublime or Notepad++ and changing the manifests include action from `Content` to `None`:

[image]

[image]

```
<None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml"/>
```

Note that doing this to a Xamarin.Android project will likely break it's ability to compile. Proceed with caution...